# How to calculate percent and add it to the amount

Tags: python

one question. My code is:

```
    preis = input("Preis: ")
    preis1 = preis / 100
    preis2 = preis1 * 1.9
    preis3 = preis + preis2
```

Lets say the preis input that the user makes is 100 , then it should do 100 / 100 = 1 (result for price1 is 1). The final output should be 101.9. But something I do not right because its not working :)

Comment: What is not working? What output you got when its not working ?

Comment: I suggest you're german, but using english variable names is more better in my oppinion.

Comment: Probably Python 2 integer division at work.

Answer (score 2):

For one, input() returns a string, so you'll need to convert that to an int.

`preis = int(input("Preis: "))`

Apart from that, your code should work, but you might want to read a style guide; you don't need to declare a new variable for every step.

Comment: We actually don't know what version OP is using, so input might be eval-ing.

Comment: This would mess up the integer division.

Comment: Hello, it works like this with a normal output. But after that I add the value to some URL like : &amount="+preis3+" , and now its not working anymore (was working before without all the calculation (only &amount="+preis+) ..

Comment: Okay, so python doesn't do much implicit conversion for you (google that phrase if it doesn't make sense to you). Before you can do anything with a variable, you have to be certain it's of the correct type. You can check type with type(x) As some have pointed out, it might be prudent to convert the string input to a float(x) instead of an int(x). Then, before appending it to a url, you need to convert it back to a string with str(x).

Answer (score 0):

```
preis = input("Preis: ")
```

You get string with this

```
preis = float(input("Preis: "))
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

Your initial division might be an integer. (I am assuming that you do not get a string input()) Thus, if you input preis as an integer less than 100, then the division result of `preis/100` is 0. If you use 100.0 in the initial division, then you set `preis1` to a float and you get a valid answer.

```
    preis = input("Preis: ")
    preis1 = preis / 100.0
    preis2 = preis1 * 1.9
    preis3 = preis + preis2
```

You should also not need to do it in 3 steps Unless you need the intermediate values later on.

```
    preis = input("Preis: ")
    preis3 = (preis * 1.9)/100 + preis
```

If the input result is a string, then you need to convert to a value (either integer or float depending on what you need to do). If it is a string, then it would be better  (even if the value is an integer) to use

```
preis = float(input("Preis: "))
```